# With NextJS Link, How to pass object clientside?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have  a Link component that I'm using and want to pass a JavaScript object to the new page I'm linking to. It seems that I can pass primitives, but not objects.

That is, I want to do something like this below but I get an empty string associated with sessionData (session.id and session.sessionSlug work).

```
                <Link
                    href={{
                        pathname: "/session", query:
                            {
                                sessionSlug: this.props.session.sessionSlug,
                                sessionId: this.props.session.id,
                                sessionData: this.props.session
                            }
                    }}
                    as={`session/${this.props.session.sessionSlug}`}>
                    <a>{this.props.session.title}</a>
                </Link>
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link

Answer (score 9):

I think you can try to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the object and then [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it back

Example

**pages/index.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link';

export default () => {
  const object = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
  };

  return (
    <Link href={{ pathname: '/about', query: { object: JSON.stringify(object) } }}>
      <a>here</a>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

**pages/about.js**

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

function About({ router: { query } }) {
  const object = JSON.parse(query.object);

  return (
    <div>
      about {object.key1} | {object.key2}
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(About);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any solution that keeps away query string to appear in URL? but with id instead? Like Next could make it appear like `/session/1` while the session object is being present?

Comment: it is okey , but when i am reload my page from browser then i was loss my object . so how to handle this?

Comment: Good idea if you want to be able to access your page with preset data by url. I would recommend using another query parser than `JSON.stringify` for readability purpose though. The npm package `query-string` works great for that. Don't forget to also parse the data back the same way you stringified it before. Use the router's `asPath` prop instead of `query` though since query is an already parsed object, and asPath is a string.