# Pass custom prop or data to Next JS Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've started messing around with Next JS, and I've come across my first hurdle.
I am creating a page displaying a bunch of podcast episodes and I am displaying a little preview card for each podcast on the homepage. The card component looks something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { kebabCase } from 'lodash';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate';

import { Episode as EpisodeInterface } from '../../interfaces';

type Props = {
  episode: EpisodeInterface;
};

const Episode: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ episode }) => {
  return (
    <Link
      href="episodes/[id]"
      as={`episodes/${episode.itunes.episode}-${kebabCase(episode.title)}`}
    >
      <div className="group transition duration-500 cursor-pointer rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-lg border border-cream-darker bg-surface hover:bg-surface-hover hover:border-surface-hover hover:text-text-hover">
        <div className="px-6 py-6">
          <div className="font-bold font-serif text-3xl mb-2">
            {episode.title}
          </div>

          <div className="transition duration-500 flex justify-between mb-2 text-gray-700 group-hover:text-text-hover">
            <span>Episode {episode.itunes.episode}</span>
            <span>{format(new Date(episode.isoDate), 'd MMMM yyyy')}</span>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-2">
            <TextTruncate line={3} text={episode.contentSnippet} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Episode;
```

Now I want to be able to pass the `episode` object to the full episode page located at `/pages/episodes/[id].tsx` that is being linked to via the `Link` element above, rather than have to refetch and filter all the episodes based upon the name of the route that I've chosen `episodes/${episode.itunes.episode}-${kebabCase(episode.title)}`.

- Is it possible to pass the entire `episode` object to the new view?
- If not, is it possible to pass some more specific data (e.g. unique id) to the view that will enable me to better identify the episode without cluttering the route with query params?

Answer (score 19):

Adding to @AmerllicA's answer,

I found a way to pass props to the target page when clicking on a `<Link>` component using `getServerSideProps`

Nextjs Link Component documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Nextjs getServerSideProps documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

You can pass a custom object to the query option of the `href` prop

```
<Link
    href={{
        pathname: "episodes/[id]",
        query: {
            id: episode.itunes.episode,
            title: episode.title
        }
    }}
    as={`episodes/${episode.itunes.episode}-${kebabCase(episode.title)}`}
 >
... button stuff
</Link>
```

in `pages/episodes/[id].js`

```
export  const getServerSideProps= (context)=> {
  console.log(context.query) 
  return {
      props: { 
         title: context.query.title //pass it to the page props
      }
  }
}
export async function getServerSideProps  (context) {
    console.log(context.query) 
    // returns { id: episode.itunes.episode, title: episode.title}
    

    //you can make DB queries using the data in context.query
    return {
        props: { 
           title: context.query.title //pass it to the page props
        }
    }
}
```

And can see the `console.log` data in the terminal to confirm the data is passed

Finally, you can use the passed props in the episode screen

```
const Episode = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.title}</div>
    )
}
```

I think this would work with `getStaticProps` as well.

Thank you for the question.

Comment: thank you this worked out perfectly for me and was easy to understand

Answer (score 9):

Actually, due to [this link](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/11327), it is an open issue and NextJS has no proper solution for it. Based on [NexJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object) you can just pass `query` params to the routed component. so I understand this is not a solution, but just right now it can fix your issue:

```js
<Link href={{ pathname: '/about', query: { data: JSON.stringify(episode) } }}>
  <a>About us</a>
</Link>
```

Then in the routed component get the query from URL and `parse` it:

```js
const RoutedComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { data } = getQueryParams(window.location.search);
  }, []);
};
```

**Note**: the [`getQueryParams`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359101/6877799) is a simple function that returns all params data after the `?` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get what you are saying but that would result in a very messy URL :-) 
I'm new to SSR and now that I think about it more it makes sense that state can not be passed from one view to another like with client side rendering.

Comment: Dear @oldo.nicho, there is another way, please see [After.js](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js). it's a great library that used `react-router` inside `next.js`. so with this, you can fix your problem. if you are ok with this tell me to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AmerllicA. I took a bit of a look at After.js and indeed it looks like it could be a nice solution, however I am currently focusing my energies on learning Next.js and I'd prefer to learn how to operate within the constraints of this library before branching out into yet another library.  Nice suggestion though and hopefully someone else will find it useful.

Comment: possibly there's a better way to do exactly the same thing using next/router, which is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132617/with-nextjs-link-how-to-pass-object-clientside) answer

Comment: This is work, I used this method. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

You can't pass data to `next/link` component.

Even if you would pass it, you won't be able to access it on server-side when a user visits the page directly or refreshes it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm new to SSR and now that I think about it more it makes sense what you are saying.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a path using template literals as below

```
href={`episodes/${episode.itunes.episode}-${kebabCase(episode.title)}`}
```

this way you can use the id in the router query in context of server methods.

But this might not really the optimal way as you must have to then split the episode and the title. what I'd suggest you to do is use the slug feature of the NextJS router for which you can visit the [documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) or follow the bellow steps.

Step 1: Rename your destination file to [...slug].js ('slug' is the genral term you can use whatever you prefer eg:[...episode].js).

Step 2: Add all the params you wish in the href prop forming a single path as below

```
href={`episodes/${episode.itunes.episode}/${kebabCase(episode.title)}/${episode.anotherProp}`}
```

Step 3: Make use of the slug in the page itself which will be returned in an array.

> For next/router (using inside the component)
>
> ```
> import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
>
> export default function SingleEpisode() {
>     const router = useRouter();
>     const { slug } = router.query;
>     const [episodeNumber, episodeTitle, episodeAnotherProp] = slug;
>     // I chose to destructure the array but you can always use indices.
>
>     // Your Business Logic.
>
>     return (
>     // Your JSX
>     )
> }
> ```
>
> For server methods (using context in getServerSideProps or
> getStaticProps)
>
> ```
> export default function SingleEpisode({episode}) {
>     // Your Component
> }
>
> export const getServerSideProps = (context) => {
>     const { slug } = context.query
>     const [episodeNumber, episodeTitle, episodeAnotherProp] = slug;
>     // I chose to destructure the array but you can always use indices.
>
>     // Your Business/API/Database Logic
>
>     return {
>         props:{
>             episode:episodeData // from your logic above.
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

use **useRouter and dynamic** of next

```
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router"; 
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const BlogDetails = dynamic(() => import("../../components/Blog-details/blog-details"))
const BlogDetails2 = dynamic(() => import("../../components/Blog-details/blog-details2"))

const router = useRouter()
console.log(router.query)

const page = router.query.blogDetails //my .js file is named blogDetails.js
  let myCustomComponent = ""
  if (page === "dijital-pazarlama") {
      myCustomComponent = <BlogDetails blog={"blog"} />
  }
  else if (page === "google-adwords-ve-firmalara-katkilari") {
      myCustomComponent = <BlogDetails2 blog={"blog"} />
  }...

return (
    {myCustomComponent}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In next.js use router as getting prob data accesss thought link

```
  <Link href={{ pathname: "/enquiry1", 
   query: { id: 5, name: "RO WATER PURIFIER 25 LPH", quantity: 1 } }}  >
  </Link>
    
    
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
    const router = useRouter();
    console.log("query", router);
    //query  id : "5" name : "RO WATER PURIFIER 25 LPH" quantity : "1"
```