# Pass data from nextjs Link component and use it in getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a dynamic route and I am trying to show the **title** in url and pass (hide) the **id** to my dynamic route and use `id` in `getStaticProps`. I have found that I can't pass data easily in nextjs as we used to pass with react router or other client routing libraries.

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096806/11866037) answer but when I `console.log(context.params)` I can't see the `id` passed from `Link`, what am I doing wrong here ?

```js
// index.js

      <Link
          href={{
            pathname: `/movie/[title]`,
            query: {
              id: movie.id, // pass the id 
            },
          }}
          as={`/movie/${movie.original_title}`}
        >
          <a>...</a>
      </Link>

// [movieId].js

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(context.params); // return { movieId: 'Mortal Kombat' }

  return {
    props: { data: "" },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `context` parameter is an object containing the following keys:

- `params` contains the route parameters for pages using dynamic routes. For example, if the page name is `[id].js` , then `params` will look like `{ id: ... }`. - [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(context.params); // return { movieId: 'Mortal Kombat' }
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

If the dynamic page looks like `/pages/[movieId].js` you can access pid in `context.params.movieId` .

You can't access "Query String" in `getStaticProps` because as the docs state,

> Because `getStaticProps` runs at build time, it does not receive data that’s only available during request time, such as query parameters or HTTP headers as it generates static HTML.

If you need "Query String", you can make use of [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering),

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.query);
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

#### Edit:

About that `Link`, you should pass the same value as a key for `query` which you use for dynamic `pathname`:

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: `/movie/[title]`,
    query: {
      title: movie.id, // should be `title` not `id`
    },
  }}
  as={`/movie/${movie.original_title}`}
>
</Link>;
```

And then in `/pages/[title].js`,

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(context.params); // return { title: 'Mortal Kombat' }
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Note how `title` is being used as the key, both in filename and the query object in `Link`.

Comment: I'm sorry had a typo error, I meant `context.params` not query.

Comment: Thanks, `getServerSideProps` works, not having same values in pathname and query was also the problem. One thing is that I am also using `getStaticPaths` and because of I now use `getServerSideProps`, I can't use `getStaticPaths` anymore. It's working fine now but Is it okay to completely remove `getStaticPaths` ?

Comment: It depends. Do you need static site optimization, then you'll have to use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`. If you are okay with SSR then `getServerSideProps` is completely fine.