# How to pass data without using props to a dynamic page in NextJS? Note: trying to reuse data and avoid network calls and tried React Context

Tags: next.js, router, next.js13

I have a NextJS project where I am working on creating a report for projects.

From the project details page there's a link to the dynamic report - which utilizes the details of the project displayed in the previous page.

File: projectInfo

```
<Link
            href={{ pathname: '/Report' }}
          >
            <span className="mt-2 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
              Create Report
            </span>
          </Link>
```

But I am unable to pass the data without using props, tried react context but it is not working as intended.

I tried using react context.

In the components, created a file called Context.jsx as shown in the example by log rocket at https://blog.logrocket.com/react-context-api-deep-dive-examples/

File:Context.jsx

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const ProjectInfoContext = createContext({});
export const ProjectInfoProvider = ProjectInfoContext.Provider;
export default ProjectInfoContext;
```

and used the provider after the fetch call in project information page

File: projectInfo.jsx

```
import {ProjectInfoProvider} from 'components/Context';

export default ProjectInfoPage() {

const [project, setProject] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch project details when the component mounts
        fetch(`/projects/get/${id}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setProject(data); // Update the project data state with the fetched data
            }
            )
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
            );
           
    },[])

return (
<ProjectInfoProvider value={project}>
                Project Title: {project.title}
//Details displayed 
 <Link
            href={{ pathname: '/Report' }}
          >
            <span className="mt-2 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
              Create Report
            </span>
          </Link>
            </ProjectInfoProvider>
);

}
```

I have tried following [Pass data from nextjs Link component and use it in getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554962/pass-data-from-nextjs-link-component-and-use-it-in-getstaticprops) but in this case the author wishes to make another network call, whereas I simply wish to utilize the data I have already received from the network call for the project info page which renders info based on the id, using the router.

Answer (score 0):

The specific code for answering this question will depend a little bit on what version of Next you are using, and more importantly whether you are using the app router or the pages router.

IMO the easiest way to do this, if you are only trying to pass the id of the project to the rendered page is to use dynamic routing. [NextJS Dynamic Routing Docs (app router)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

Assuming you are using the app router:

**1. Make a file with the path `/app/Reports/[id]/page.tsx`**

Inside this file you would declare your component with the basic structure as follows

```
import React from 'react'

const page = ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const projectId = params.id

  return (
    <<YOUR CODE HERE>>
  )
}

export default page
```

**2. Link to this route from anywhere you need**

You can do this using the next `<Link>` component and the projectId you want to link to as follows.

```
const projectId = <<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>>
.
.
.
<Link href={'/Reports/' + projectId}>
  Create Report
</Link>
```

In this way, you can access the id of your report and render accordingly.

Comment: I am using Next 13, but have stuck with pages router - because I found more documentation and examples for it online. I have multiple fields (at least 5) which I need to pass to the dynamic page, and as of right now I am using react-redux but it's not working properly.

Comment: Ahhh. In that case this solution will not work as well for you! (There is dynamic routing with the pages router, but if you need to send multiple fields that won't work) Thanks for the extra info. After looking again at your solution, it is not clear exactly where you have placed the context provider. Context providers pass 'state' to all of their children components, so if you want to set context in one place, and access it in another, you have to make sure the provider component is high enough in the tree that both places you access context are children components.

Comment: Yep! And that's where the issue arises. And I need help with it.

Comment: I have placed the context file in components, and in projectInfo, which is in the projects folder based on the router /projects/projectInfo, the context is created after the fetch call as shown above

Comment: I am sorry if my explanation was confusing. The file location of the context provider is not as important as where you have placed it in the HTML tree. Usually it is best to put your context provider as high in the tree as possible. (In your root file is usually best). To put it another way, if you were to open your component tree using the chrome react developer tools plugin, your context provider would need to be 'higher' in the tree than your fetch call and your reports page. Context providers can only 'share data' with its children. That is what I am trying to verify. Does that make sense?