# Send props to a loaded component using next/link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import TestAcademy from './test-academy.js';    
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      const router = useRouter()
      const [approved, setApproved] = useState(false)

      ...

    return(
    <Link href='/test-academy' //pass approved as a prop>
        
    </Link>  )
```

So, I want to load the component TestAcademy, and when it loads I can access inside them, to *props.approved*

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Pass custom prop or data to Next JS Link component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927604/pass-custom-prop-or-data-to-next-js-link-component)? You can't pass props directly, but you can pass data as query params instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link
    href={{
    pathname: "/test-academy",
    query: { approved: approved }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access custom params in a different page you need to pass with the `<Link>` component the query as well.

It will look something like this:

```
<Link href={{ pathname: "/something", query: { key: "someValue" } }}>
  User Details
</Link>
```

your URL will then look something like this, I assume now that `http://localhost:3000/`, hence dev env.

e.g.
`http://localhost:3000/something?key=someValue`

as you can see you now have attached to your baseURL your params.

in your component where you would like to retrieve this data you can use `useSearchParams` and retrieve them.
e.g.:

```
"use client";

import { items } from "./SettingsTab.helper";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export const ComponentA = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const customParamKey = searchParams.get("key");

  // your logic and component view output
  ...
};
```